# An error occurred (Unauthorized) using boto3 upload file with python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, cloudflare, unauthorized

I encountered an error while trying to upload a file to the Storage using boto3 on CloudFlare R2.

Until a few days ago, there were no issues with this code, but suddenly, an issue arose, and it's difficult to identify the cause.

I have been running the code in various environments such as Python 3.7, 3.9, and 3.11, and I have been using the appropriate version of boto3 for each of these environments.

The code is as follows:

```
class CloudApi:

    def init( self, endpoint_url, access_key_id, secret_access_key, bucket_name ):
         self.endpoint_url = endpoint_url 
         self.access_key_id = access_key_id 
         self.secret_access_key = secret_access_key 
         self.bucket_name = bucket_name
    
    def boto3_client(self):
    
        s3 = boto3.client(
            service_name="s3",
            endpoint_url=self.endpoint_url,
            aws_access_key_id=self.access_key_id,
            aws_secret_access_key=self.secret_access_key,
        )
    
        return s3
    
    def upload_file(self, path_local, path_cloud):
        s3 = self.boto3_client()
        s3.upload_file(path_local, self.bucket_name, path_cloud)

r2 = CloudApi( endpoint_url="", access_key_id="", secret_access_key="", bucket_name="")

r2.upload_file(path_local='', path_cloud='')
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/cloud_utils.py", line 182, in <module>
    test.upload_file(path_file_local='~/test.json',
  File "~/cloud_utils.py", line 121, in upload_file
    create_multipart_upload_response = s3.create_multipart_upload(
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 964, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (Unauthorized) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Unauthorized
```

What should I do to resolve this issue? Unlike AWS, I'm not sure about the policies or IAM aspects that need to be adjusted on CloudFlare.

Comment: The error clearly says that you are `Unauthorized` to perform such an action. Contact your aws admin to setup correct permissions for you.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks your comment, but actually i'm using cloudflare r2 not aws.
 i wanna find admin setup on cloudflare, but i don't know how to do.